# Is there any way to get the data out of Default Constructor and use it in other method?

Tags: java, swing, oop, constructor

I am trying to build a project where I will be exporting the data from h2db and store it as CSV file.
I am planning on taking the destination path for the CSV file(which is to be saved) from the user.
Class name is Export and here in default constructor swing events are happening.
I want the value of ***getSelectedFile()***,(that is the path selected by user) to be able to use in another method.
I have created class variable - path of string type when trying to use the value all I am getting is null.
Thanks in Advance :)

Here is the code,

```
public class export extends JFrame{
   private BufferedWriter fileWriter;
   private JPanel contentPane;
   private static JTextField tableName;
   private JButton exportButton;
   private JButton PathButton;
   private String path;
   private String temp;
   
public export() {
         //Some labels and textfields  
  
       JFrame frame = new JFrame("CSV Export");
       PathButton = new JButton("Destination Path");
       PathButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
           public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
               JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
               fileChooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
               int option = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(frame);
               if(option == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                   File file = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
                   path = fileChooser.getSelectedFile().toString();
                   label.setText("Folder Selected: " + file.getName());
                   System.out.println(file.getName());
                   System.out.println("getCurrentDirectory(): " 
                           + fileChooser.getCurrentDirectory());
                   System.out.println("getSelectedFile() : " 
                           + fileChooser.getSelectedFile());
                   path = fileChooser.getSelectedFile().toString();
                   exportButton.setEnabled(true);
               }else {
                   label.setText("Open Command canceled");
                   exportButton.setEnabled(false);
               }
           }
       });
       PathButton.setFont(new Font("Tahoma",Font.PLAIN,13));
       PathButton.setBounds(120,230,130,30);
       contentPane.add(PathButton);   
   }
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't be "getting data out" of a constructor. That's not what a constructor is for: a constructor is solely for initializing an instance of a class. Use a method if you want to get data.

Comment: "in default constructor swing events are happening" sounds like bad design too. Also this class is called `export`, not `Export`, which is against conventions. Your fields are all `null` because you never initialised them with anything, except for `PathButton` which is also named wrong.

Comment: Your class extends JFrame and then in the constructor your create another JFrame, so you have two JFrame instances. Don't extend JFrame!